# Insert a specific date in Mysql using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date

Okay here is the scenario, I need to insert a specific date in mysql. Everytime I insert this date I get 0000-00-00.

Everytime a user pays between the 1st and the 20th of the month then the wb_due-date column would increment the month by 1

Ex. 
I have a default value of `wb_paid-date = 2013-10-15 and wb_due-date = 2013-10-20`. 
Now User1 Paid on 2013-10-15 and after I clicked button, the date saved on wb_due-date was 0000-00-00 instead of 2013-11-20

Take a look at my code

```
Function iterate(ByVal d As Date) As String
        Dim m As Integer = d.Month
        If d.Month >= 1 And d.Month <= 11 Then
            m += 1
        ElseIf d.Month = 12 Then
            m = 1
        End If
        Return m
    End Function

cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_billing(wb_paid-date, wb_due-date) 
VALUES(CURDATE(), iterate(Now.Date) , con)
```

Comment: Your SQL is not valid. You cannot call VB functions from SQL sent to a MySQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's fix your function:

```
Function iterate(ByVal d As DateTime) As String
    Return d.AddMonths(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
End Function
```

Also, if you're putting a string date into command, you're almost certainly doing something wrong. Let's just do this:

```
Function iterate(ByVal d As DateTime) As DateTime
    Return d.AddMonths(1)
End Function
```

Then we'll fix your Sql Command:

```
cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_billing(wb_paid-date, wb_due-date) VALUES(CURDATE(), ? " , con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = iterate(Today)
```

Comment: I am having the error "Input string was not in format", I followed your answer